# Accessing the value of a Preprocessor Macro definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macros, c-preprocessor, stringification

If I add a macro "FOO=bar" under GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS (or Preprocessor Macros if you use XCode"), what would be the best way to access the value of "FOO"?

Currently, I use the clumsy:

```
    #define MACRO_NAME(f) #f
    #define MACRO_VALUE(f)  MACRO_NAME(f)

    #ifdef FOO
        NSLog(@"%s", MACRO_VALUE(FOO));
    #else
        NSLog(@"undefined");
    #endif
```

This will output "bar"

Surely, there must be a better/cleaner way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are doing is *the way* to *stringize* (or *stringify*) macro values. The indirection is unavoidable.

This is mentioned in the GCC preprocessor [manual section (archived link)](http://web.archive.org/web/20160304001326/http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) that Rob linked to:

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSLog(@"%s", #FOO);
```

See [Stringification](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html). It's the technique you're already using. What was wrong with it?

Comment: This would result in `NSLog(@"%s", #bar);` after preprocessing - the indirection through another macro is needed to allow for macro expansion.

Comment: It means you can't turn a preprocessor string macro into an NSString constant right? (Because as soon as you do [NSString stringWithFormat:macroString] it ceases to be a constant initializer.)

Comment: One of my projects had turned preprocessor string macros into NSString constant like this:
#define kString "String"
#define kNSString @kString