# XCUITests - Passing in environment variables via command line

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-ui-testing

I'm attempting to pass a value to my XCUITest via command line. I'm aware that it's possible to do this for an XCTest (non-UI) in the following way:

> xcodebuild -verbose test -workspace MyWorkspace.xcworkspace
>   -derivedDataPath derivedData -scheme "MyScheme" -configuration Debug SYMROOT="$(pwd)"/build -destination platform="iOS
>   Simulator",name="iPad Air",OS=10.2 -only-testing:UITests/UITests
>   -resultBundlePath logfiles MY_SETTING="setting_value" MY_OTHER_SETTING="setting_value_2"

This, however, doesn't seem to work in my XCUITest, as the code does not enter the #ifdef MY_SETTING block. Is there another way I can pass values to my XCUITest via command line, or is it not possible?

Comment: Set `MY_SETTING` before calling `xcodebuild...`.

Comment: @shallowThought that did not work.

Comment: I am wrong than. Sorry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your answers below, I found this answer which eventually worked for me. The great people at Applitools shed some light on this issue for me, detailed steps are as follows:

> The most important step is to make Xcode know about the variables we
>   are going to pass from command line.
>
> Lets call our variable TEST_VAR. To do this follow these steps please:
>
> 1) Open to Xcode, select TEST TARGET(not target of application)
>   https://www.evernote.com/l/AR0BF8Te8_hFGYON8jKqIkv3grnwFky16tc
>
> 2) Select “Build Settings” and add in the “Preprocessor Macros”
>   section TEST_VAR=$(TEST_VAR)
>
> https://www.evernote.com/l/AR1b4QRysBlDRro3sbKH1hSy6s_2s_Qkxnw
>
> 3) Add new user-define setting by tapping “+” button and selecting
>   “Add User-Defined Setting”
>   https://www.evernote.com/l/AR0qflFqN2lIEoKVVzUUYRArM49Qb1d2TUE
>
> 4) Set a default value for your new custom setting
>   https://www.evernote.com/l/AR32JBfPDhFIN76ZlJjq1eV7v8bry9WImfE
>
> Now variable TEST_VAR is ready to use.
>
> This is an example how I pass it to the test. My test project is
>   inside a workspace. So I open Terminal and go to the destination
>   folder of my workspace.
>
> xcodebuild -workspace workspace_name\ workspace.xcworkspace/ -scheme
>   YourSchemeName -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS
>   Simulator,name=iPhone 6,OS=10.2'
>   -only-testing:TestTargetName/TestCaseName/testName TEST_VAR=1988 test
>
> Inside the test I can get the value of TEST_VAR variable somehow like
>   this: NSLog(@"TEST_VAR %li", (long)TEST_VAR);

However, I also needed to define another preprocessor macro to unwrap the string value of the value I passed in, as described here: [Accessing the value of a Preprocessor Macro definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261763/accessing-the-value-of-a-preprocessor-macro-definition).

So to retrieve the string value, I did something like:

```
NSLog(@"TEST_VAR %s", MACRO_VALUE(TEST_VAR))
```

Answer (score 5):

If you need pass the **environment variables** from your schema to XCUITes, modify the XCTestCase -> app.launchEnvironment object, on each test class of this way:

**Swift 3**

```
override func setUp(){
    app.launchEnvironment = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, yes, you are missing two steps though.

1. Set up your Scheme to have an environment variable that has `MY_SETTING` set as it's value.
2. `if let mySetting = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment['MY_SETTING'] { 
   // do whatever you want because it is defined 
   }`

Kind of a dupe of [Accessing user defined variables passed in from xcodebuild command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23284829/accessing-user-defined-variables-passed-in-from-xcodebuild-command-line/42496856#42496856)

Answer (score 0):

There is no native method for passing values to UI tests via xcodebuild. You could use a perl one-liner to replace a value in your project before running UI tests:

```
perl -pi -e 's/valueToReplace/replacementValue/g' <path to file to modify>
```

I've used this method in the past to replace the base URL in a project in order to run UI tests against a mock server.